# Windows 7 Audio Mixer - Alternative?

Tags: windows-7, audio, mixer

Does anyone know of an app that could serve as an alternative to the mixer in Windows 7?

I am looking to quickly adjust the volume of various devices easily (preferably with a keystroke to open the panel perhaps?).

If anyone knows of any other tools/shortcuts, please post them here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found somewhat of a solution:

1. Search for Volume in Windows 7
2. "Adjust System Volume" that appears in results
3. Right click on the icon - pin to task bar
4. Move the icon to be the first, or which ever spot youd like
5. Windows key + (position number) will open the volume mixer from anywhere you are working in Windows 7.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Also, try creating a short cut to `C:\Windows\System32\SndVol.exe`.
I setup my Logitech mouse setpoint software to launch that program whenever I press one of the customized button.